# Printing letters in text based hangman game

Tags: java, arrays, text

So I'm trying to make a hangman game where it generates a random word from a file of words, asks the user for a letter, and then goes through the word and either prints the letter where it occurs or prints a "_ ". I know my "sorry no matches found" is incorrect right now, but I'm having trouble being able to keep the last correct letter guessed in place when I print the word so far

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.io.*;
    public class hangman

    {
public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner hangman = null; 

    try 
    {
        // Create a scanner to read the file, file name is parameter
            hangman = new Scanner (new File("C:\\Users\\Phil\\Desktop\\hangman.txt"));
        } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
        System.out.println ("File not found!");
        // Stop program if no file found
        System.exit (0);
        }



    String[] list = new String[100];
    int x = 0;

    while(hangman.hasNext())
    {
        list[x] = hangman.nextLine();
        x++;
    }

    Random randWord = new Random();
    String word = "";
    int wordNum = 0;
    boolean stillPlaying = true;

    wordNum = randWord.nextInt(12);
    word = list[wordNum];
    System.out.println("The word has "+word.length()+" letters");

    Scanner letter = new Scanner(System.in);
    String guess = "";

    while(stillPlaying = true)
    {           

        System.out.println("Guess a letter a-z");
        guess = letter.nextLine();
        for(int y = 0; y<word.length(); y++)
        {
            if(word.contains(guess))
            {
                if(guess.equals(word.substring(y,y+1)))
                {
                    System.out.print(guess+" ");
                }
                else
                    System.out.print("_ ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, no matches found");
            }
        }
    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You might like an addition array. i.e. your char array is 100 characters long, so you could make another array 100 items long. This second array could contains 0 and 1's. Initially set it all to 0's, if the letter in the position array2[x] is guessed, then set the value to 1. This would let you use a for loop on the second array,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array2); i++){
     if (array2[i] == 0)
          print "_";
     else 
          print stringArray[i]
}
```

The above probably isn't correct code but the idea should be there, you just use another array the same size to keep track of the letters to see if they're guessed or not guessed (1 or 0). I hope this helps

Sorry this solution is in C, I didn't see import, or tag my first read.

array2 would just be an integer array, and you can access the elements similar to string array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < finalString.length; i++){
    if (array2[i] == 0){
        copy "_" to finalString position i;
    }
    else {
        copy stringArray position i to finalString position i;
    }

}
Now you can print finalString and it should show the proper string with _ and letters!
```

Comment: Alright, so this is definitely a step closer, but instead of printing the letter in the correct space, the program is printing the letter that occurs at the index of where the loop is currently

Comment: In the for loop use an array to store the correct string, an array to store values 0/1 (to check if the letter has been guessed) and then another array to hold a print string.

In your for loop copy the _ and letters to the third array and print that.

e.g.
I put the code into the answer since it looked bad written here.